# Contract library as a repository

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, interface, module

I am working on a C# project that is comprised by the Clients project (Clients.csproj) I have a DAL library that gets data for clients from the database (Products.DAL.csproj). Inside Products.DAL.SQL.csproj I have an interface IProductsService which has a method GetProducts() (reads product from MS SQL database). Now I have the requirement to add an extra data source so I created another project (Products.DAL.Mongo.csproj). I need to implement IProductsService interface in this new project but I dont want to reference the Products.DAL.SQL.csproj to get the interface. What is the recommended way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: IProductService is a DataService for the application. It describes how the application will ask for/send data. So that interface belongs more to the application and less to the DAL. The concrete implementations for IProductService belong to the DAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do a core project who holds all your business classes and interfaces in folders so the namespaces will be Products.Core.Business and Products.Core.Interface.
All you'll have to do is referencing the core project.

This way you have to implement the IProductService in both Products.DAL.SQL and Products.DAL.Mongo without referencing the SQL project.

[EDIT] :

I'll quote a [french post](https://www.infoq.com/fr/news/2013/11/ddd-ground-up) about DDD :

Your solution will have 5 layers :

1. **Infrastructure** : services infrastructure (interfaces)
2. **Repository** : data access layer and persistance
3. **Domain** : domain layer with the entities and business logic
4. **Services** : provides services to your users
5. **Client** : web application or client application who consumes your services.

Comment: But if DAL references Core project it immediately gets accesss to Core.Business whereas it needs Core.Contracts only.

Comment: So what I'll do here (I assume you're using visual studio) is : I'll create a solution folder for core projects, then in this folder I'll have my business, contracts, ... projects

Comment: I think it's not a bad think to split those in separate projects, especially if you have a lot of them. It provides a bit more readability and easier to maintain.

Comment: In a Domain Driven Design what would be your approach?